# SSRS+MDX+scalar axis -> Evaluate Y-values for missing X-values

Tags: reporting-services, ssas, mdx

My MDX-query retrieves about 10 columns names (one is actually the key EVENT_ID - to be used in the report for linking purpose and drilldown behavour) 
+ a time measure (time losses per day in our factory) 
+ a budget measure.

Since I have all these columns, I will not be able to "Include empty cells" -> results in miljons of rows.

I am presenting the time losses in a column chart + evaluating a moving avereage line (from code behind, quite complex..) + presenting a budget line. 
I have put, using subreports, a series of charts in an top-down layout, only chart-series are changed using parameters, so I wish all charts to look the same (same start- and ending point on the x-axis) when scolling though them, only the series group will be changed -> comparisation will be easy.

**My problem is,**

Since the MDX-query is only reporting days where we actually have time losses,

- I will not be able to avaluate a moving avereage value for days occuring after the last day in the dataset.
- I am not be able to show a budget value for days occuring after the last day in the dataset.

This results in a very unpleasent layout or the subreports, where some charts has values the last month/day and does not...

Please, has anyone solved any similar problem?
I have eaven tried solving this using the Lookup-function between an other DataSet holding all dates, but the use of seriesGroups makes it kind of unuseable.

**Added info:**

Look at image below

**da*n I only have 6 point, need 10 to post images :/**

The thin line evaluates a gliding average ok, but I am not able to populate a value after **mar** since my dataset does not have values after **mars**.

The image should show a column chart Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May. I have values and a gliding average evaluated only for Feb, Mar -> the gliding average will not show after Mar. I would like it to be evaluated also Apr and May. The gliding avereage is evaluated from code-behind:

```
iif(DateValue(Fields!Date.Value)>=DateValue(First(Fields!Date.Value, "TimeData"))
,Code.movAvg.movingAverage(
    Sum(Fields!Time.Value,"CategoryGroup")
    ,DateValue(Min(Fields!Date.Value, "TimeData"))
    ,DateValue(Fields!Date.Value)
    ,DateValue(Max(Fields!Date.Value, "TimeData"))
    ,Parameters!Type.Value
    ,"TOTAL"
)
,Nothing
```

)

But this code is not executed for "empty" Dates...

I see two options:

1. Change the mdx query to give me 0-values for all periods (include empty cells?)
2. Or somehow in SSRS able to populate values for time-periods not existing in the dataset

If I go for option 1, I need to reduce the field-count in my query (current 10 is not ok), but since one of the report-parameters is actually mapped to 5 of these fields (abillity to change group-by behavour) I need to make the query dynamic, evaluated fron concatenated strings which results in no abillity to use the query designer ever after...

Thats why I was aiming for option 2. But I have started to understand option 1 is the only was to go...

Comment: How do you populate you date dimension?  Is it based on only days that exists in facts or all dates?

Comment: I only view days that exists in the fact, otherwize I will get millions of rows since I have about 10 column in the query...  

**Sincething like this on rows:**
NON EMPTY { ([Date].[Date].[Date].ALLMEMBERS * [Department].[Department].[Department].ALLMEMBERS * ... ) }

Comment: Can you show some sample output of what you are getting and what you need?

Comment: Ok, I will try to describe in more detail, I am not quite comfortable with this editor, missing new line for example... the info will be posten above in the main question.

Comment: Ok. But how do ppl know I actually have solved the problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have solved this now, doing this:

> I created two datasets in SSRS.

1. This dataset included all dates in the period, and all "Measures", no other dimension attributes in the MDX-query.
2. This dataset included only the NON EMPTY dates in the period, and the main measure (hours), and all dimension attributes I have interest in (about 10 attributes).

> Then I set dataset #1 (all dates are showing) in my chart, and where I had interest in showing dimension attributes, I used the SSRS function **LookupSet** to join data between the datasets (i joined data on the date field).
>   Not the most beautiful solution, but it sure worked out good in the end.